# JQuery Send data to page using jQuery Post and data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I'm having a bit of difficulty conceptualising this: I have some data stored to a button:

```
var input2 = '<button id="viewmap1" class="viewmap">Find on Map</button>';
        //MAKE DATA
        $(input2).data('longlat', coords);
```

Now I want to send that data to another page. I understand I am to use jQuery post, eg:

```
$.post("test.html", { func: "getNameAndTime" },
  function(data){
    alert("Hello"); 
  }, "json");
```

But im not entirely sure how to go about it. Can any one point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: when you send data ? after click somthing element or another?

Comment: can you update your question and adding some code again, example click button code,and what doyou want if data is sended to be better answer..?

Comment: for what you want to send data to another page?\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending data to a different page isn't as simple as it sounds. If it were simple, crackers could manipulate all the other pages that you currently have open in browser tabs.

When you call `$.post()`, that just sends data to the server, not to another page. The URL is a way to tell the server how to process the data but it doesn't magically connect you to the browser tab/window which has `test.html` open.

The usual solution is to use a single page which contains the button and the elements to display the results (a.k.a "view"). You send the POST request and then update the view in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(input2).on('click', function(){
 // do your post stuffs
});
```

then need to trigger the button click

```
$(input2).click();
```